# Immutable Value of "Struct" only only has mutating members named "Function"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, xcode6

I have an error and I have been trying to figure it out but can't find the right solution. Thanks in advance!

```
struct PrizeItem {

    enum Rank {
        case Ok //Purple
        case Good //Blue
        case Epic //Green
        case Rare //Yellow
        case ExtremelyRare //Red
    }



    let name : String
    let description : String

    let rank : Rank


    let identifier : String

    let color : UIColor 

    var prizeIsActive : Bool! //<-- Important

    //Important Functions
    mutating func setToActive(){
        prizeIsActive = true
    }
    mutating func setToNotActive(){
        prizeIsActive = false
    }


}
```

Now when I try to run this function:

```
func setPrizeToActive(prize:PrizeItem){

        prize.setToActive() <-- error here

    }
```

The error says the following:

> Immutable value of type PrizeItem only has mutating members named setToActive

Thanks for help!

Comment: You should mark Rich's answer as correct.

Comment: The previous answer doesn't work as you expect.  See my answer for details.

Comment: The above code raises a few questions. Why do you want to have functions that only exist to change the value of a public Bool? I would also question the idea of having an implicitly unwrapped Bool...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An earlier answer suggested changing it to:

```
func setPrizeToActive(var prize:PrizeItem){
    prize.setToActive() 
}
```

This solves the compile error, but it doesn't do anything useful. `prize` is still a copy of the value passed in, and even though `setToActive()` modifies this copy, it is then immediately thrown away. If you want the structure that is passed to `setPrizeToActive` to be modified, then prize should be marked as `inout`:

```
func setPrizeToActive(inout prize: PrizeItem) {
    prize.setToActive()
}
```

and called with:

```
// make sure myprize is declared with var
setPrizeToActive(&myprize)
```

Alternatively, you could make `PrizeItem` a class.  Since classes are reference types, the `prize` passed in will be modified as you expect.